# Centered text with background color all the way right

Tags: html, css, text, background, background-color

I was asked to code an unusual shape background color on some centered text.

The text should be centered and it's background color should continue all the way right of the parent element.

Here is the desired output :

[image: centered text with background color all the way right]

I have never seen anything like this so I don't even know where to start. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Upload your image to a site such as http://imgur.com/ then post the link in your question. Somebody will edit it for you.

Comment: Question is Unclear. [Jsfiddle.net's](http://jsfiddle.net/) fiddle can make it clear.

Comment: So here is the picture: [link](http://imgur.com/Z7qYRD4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element to make the black background continue on the right :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/P96mS/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div>
    <span>Some text with</span><br/>
    <span>unusual background</span><br/>
    <span>color</span>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
div{
    float:right;
    padding-right:150px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}

span{
    display:inline-block;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:1.4em;
    margin:0;
}
span:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:1.4em;
    right:0;
    background:inherit;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand well your problem, but try to mix these concepts:

HTML:

```
 <div id="parent">
        <p id="son">Some text with unusual background color</p>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementsById("parent").style.background="red";
    document.getElementsById("son").style.background="blue";
</script>
```

try to change the son and the parent colors.