# CSS Background Color to Text on Posts (Tumblr)

Tags: text, colors, background

I'm trying to change the background color of the text on my posts...and want the background URL image of the page to remain as is. Right now I have:

```css
body {

            font-family: {font:Font}, arial;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: {color:Body Text};
            position: center;
            line-height: 24px;
            line-height: 1.5em;
            background-image: url(SOME URL);
            background-attachment: fixed;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

        }
a {
            color: {color:Body Text};
            opacity: .5;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .like_button:hover + .like_text {
            opacity: 1;
            background-color: black;
        }
```

Can someone lend a hand? Writing `background-color: black;` in the body doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another div that will be used inside the body and change it’s background color to the one you want.You can also change the `<p>` background color on css.

An basic example of that would be the following:

**mystyle.css**

```
    body {

    font-family: {font:Font}, arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: {color:Body Text};
    position: center;
    line-height: 24px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background-image: url("https://images7.alphacoders.com/411/thumb-1920-411820.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

}
a {
    color: {color:Body Text};
    opacity: .5;
    background-color: black;
}
p
{
    text-decoration-color: floralwhite;

}
#post
{
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity: 70;
    background-color:rgba(189, 213, 239, .4);;
}
```

**site.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="post">
        <p> A lot of text here.</p>
        <p> A lot of text here.</p>
        <p> A lot of text here.</p>
        <p> A lot of text here.</p>
        <p> A lot of text here.</p>
        <p> A lot of text here.</p>
        <p> A lot of text here.</p>
        <p> A lot of text here.</p>
        <p> A lot of text here.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

--

What I would apply it to: 
[image: Description of image]

Comment: What would the div look like?

Comment: #post{backgroud-color: thecoloryouwant}

Comment: Well, I handled it that way in an school project and worked pretty fine for me, could you share your html piece of code where you use those divs, so I can take a better look?

Comment: My HTML code is just what's above plus a <div> {background-color: black; </div>

But maybe it's in this section:

 <div id="content">
                {block:Posts}
                
of my HTML code that I should add something about background color?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a litte late, but, I think I didn't understood, do you want something like this: https://imgur.com/a/i4EG0id ?

Comment: I'm editting the post to include the css and HTML code to produce the image I just send, if that's not what you wanted, try to explain it better please.

Comment: Hey, I actually know how to get the result you linked. But no, I just want the text in the posts to have a background color. Kind of like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753845/centered-text-with-background-color-all-the-way-right 

I edited the post with a picture of why

Comment: Ok, I’ll try to post an answer soon

Comment: But what you posted looks cool. I don't know, I need a background color to the yellow text and if I change the background to the post to black then thats a lot of black and almost wipes out the greenery entirely. Thats why I wanted just the text.

Comment: I’ll put another answer with an different alternative, check it out.

Comment: Do I paste the site.html code right into the customize code section on Tumblr? Where should it be pasted in terms of the rest of the code?

Comment: Actually, you should copy the p.a section of the other answer to your css, and put class=”a” on each <p> you use

Comment: Or, if you want to use the example I showed on the image, just copy the CSS

Comment: The p/a/and #post section pasted into my css don't do anything. I think its bc nowhere have I managed to write a section for -inside the post-. #post alone doesn't do it, I don't think.

Comment: I couldn’t understand what you just said.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="post">
    <p class="a"> A lot of text here.</p>
     <p class="a"> A lot of text here.</p>
      <p class="a"> A lot of text here.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {

font-family: {font:Font}, arial;
font-size: 16px;
color: {color:Body Text};
position: center;
line-height: 24px;
line-height: 1.5em;
background-image: url("https://images7.alphacoders.com/411/thumb-1920-411820.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

}
p.a
{
 color:white;
 background-color:black;

}
#post
{
margin-top: 200px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
opacity: 70;
background-color:rgba(189, 213, 239, .4);;
}
```